# how to insert data from csv file into database using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, csv, sql-server-2012

I am trying to insert data that is saved in csv format.i tried the below code but the problem is when i run the code it only save data from the second line.can anyone correct my code so that i can save my data from the first line.

CODE:-

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        csvInsert();
    }

    public void csvInsert()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectme"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        //DataTable dt = new DataTable("insert");
        string filename = "C:\\Users\\Aowi\\Desktop\\asdf.csv";

        SqlTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader file = new StreamReader(filename))
            {

                CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(file, true, '\t');
                SqlBulkCopy copy = new SqlBulkCopy(conn, SqlBulkCopyOptions.KeepIdentity, transaction);
                copy.DestinationTableName = "[Live]";
                copy.WriteToServer(csv);
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            transaction.Rollback();
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }

    }
```

Saved in Database as:-

[image]

csv file is:-

```
1,Germany,? - ?,Portugal
2,half-time,(? - ?),
3
4,Milorad Mazic (Serbia),
5,Iran,? - ?,Nigeria
6,half-time,(? - ?),
7
8,Carlos Vera (Ecuador),
9,Ghana,? - ?,USA
10,half-time,(? - ?),
```

Desired output is insert each and every data from the csv file to each cell in database.

Comment: What is `CsvReader`? Unsure how it works, given that it _seems_ it's a `tab` that you specified as the delimiter (instead of comma)...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the CSV reader expects a header row. Try adding a header to the top and see if that resolves. Try passing FALSE to the CSVReader, as well. It looks like that flag might be used to signify if you have a header row or not.

Comment: i passed false to csvreader and it showed the 1st line too now but another problem occurred now it is on single column  rather than splitting into multiple column in the database.can you help?